# Abstract Factory Implementation C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory-method, abstract-factory

I'm learning Factory pattern and I've implemented this simple example of an abstract factory. I've followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEk7B_GUErc) video a little bit while writing this small example. Is there anything anti-pattern or wrong in this example?

**I've created two different Pizzas**

```
public interface IPizza
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class NewYorkPizza : IPizza
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "NewYork Pizza";
}

public class ItalianPizza : IPizza
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Italian Pizza";
}
```

**Then relevant Pizza factories**

```
public interface IPizzaFactory
{
    IPizza Create();
}

public class NewYorkPizzaFactory : IPizzaFactory
{
    public IPizza Create()
    {
        return new NewYorkPizza();
    }
}

public class ItalianPizzaFactory : IPizzaFactory
{
    public IPizza Create()
    {
        return new ItalianPizza();
    }
}
```

**Then created an abstract factory**

```
public interface IAbstractPizzaFactory
{
    IPizzaFactory GetNewYorkPizzaFactory();
    IPizzaFactory GetItalianPizzaFactory();
}

public class AbstractPizzaFactory : IAbstractPizzaFactory
{
    public IPizzaFactory GetNewYorkPizzaFactory()
    {
        return new NewYorkPizzaFactory();
    }

    public IPizzaFactory GetItalianPizzaFactory()
    {
        return new NewYorkPizzaFactory();
    }
}
```

> Notice that I'm avoiding `abstract` class way and using only Interface
> to achieve kind of same thing and although, it looks correct to me,
> but I'm confuse here if it's the right approach or not?

**And then I can use it like this**

```
public class Test
{
    private readonly IAbstractPizzaFactory _abstractPizzaFactory;

    public Test(IAbstractPizzaFactory abstractPizzaFactory)
    {
        _abstractPizzaFactory = abstractPizzaFactory;
    }

    private void CreatePizza()
    {
        IPizza newYorkPizza = _abstractPizzaFactory.GetNewYorkPizzaFactory().Create();
        Console.WriteLine(newYorkPizza.Name);

        IPizza italianPizza = _abstractPizzaFactory.GetItalianPizzaFactory().Create();
        Console.WriteLine(italianPizza.Name);
    }

}
```

Comment: [The Factory chapter from *Head First Design Patterns*](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-design/0596007124/ch04.html).

Answer (score 1):

The main idea behind *abstract factory* is that you have **multiple different products** (sometimes referred as product family) and **multiple different factories** and you want to **centralise the common theme** without relying on concrete products.

Your example tries to implement the *abstract factory* and *factory method* patterns at the same time in a strange way. The *factory method* tries to hide the creation process of a **single product**. (Only at run-time you get the information to know which concrete type you need.)

I would suggest to read [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739611/what-are-the-differences-between-abstract-factory-and-factory-design-patterns) thoroughly and choose the appropriate pattern for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

[As @slepic pointed out in the comments, abstract factory with only one creational method may not be considered a real abstract factory. If you only need to create instances of one type, use [factory method](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method) instead]

You slightly misunderstood the idea here:
[image]
*Abstract factory* is (as the name suggests) just a factory which is abstract, meaning that it lacks a concrete implementation. Abstract pizza factory doesn't produce pizza factories (it's not a factory of factories), it **is** a pizza factory.

You can look at a good example [here](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/abstract-factory/csharp/example) and read more [here](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/abstract-factory).

---

Unrelated to the main question but also important: you made `IPizza` an interface but abstract class would fit this case better since it defines the identity of the class: you won't be able to define fields or constructors in an interface.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I've two questions then; `IPizzaFactory` is my abstract factory and now i need to use it somewhere. Because `IPizzaFactory` have two different implementations `NewYorkPizzaFactory` and `ItalianPizzaFactory`. I can constructor inject it using `Func` to get a specific factory I want. But then what's the difference? I mean to get a specific factory I'll have to use some kind of `Enum` or `String`. Are we really supposed to do it like that? I created `IAbstractPizzaFactory` to get rid of this problem basically...

Comment: 2: Yes, I made `IPizza` an interface instead of making it an `abstract` class. Is it not okay if I don't have fields or constructor usage...? both implementations can have their own relevant fields or methods.

Comment: @RaoArman why do you need an `Enum` or `String` for that? And why do you need `Func`? `IAbstractPizzaFactory` lists every possible factory which is against [open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) so I don't see what problem it helps to get rid of.

Comment: `IPizzaFactory` have wo implementations. if i use dependency injection of `IPizzaFactory` and want `ItalianPizzaFactory` then how will i do that? Or can we do this directly in viewModel  `new ItalianPizzaFactory()` ??

Comment: @RaoArman let's say you want to create restaraunts of national cousine: `class Restaraunt { IPizzaFactory kitchen }`. You can make an american restaraunt: `new Restaraunt(new NewYorkPizzaFactory())` or an italian restaraunt: `new Restaraunt(new ItalianPizzaFactory())`. And then serve pizza: `Pizza pizza = restaraunt.kitchen.Create()`.

Comment: @RaoArman as for the other question, interfaces are a way to specify that certain objects are expected to implement certain behaviour (methods declared in the interface) while classes are templates for creating objects. Pizza falls into the second category.

Comment: I fully and enthusiastically endorse the idea of abstract classes in lieu of a mere `interface`.  Factory is about building complete objects, not just instantiating Typed object shells. If there was a "prepare pizza" process an `interface` could  not  enforce any method call order.  I've worked with lots of real-life  code all implementing the same interface yet many with buggy functioning because every implementation is written from scratch. And of course the buggy ones were buggy differently.

Comment: You're absolutely wrong. Abstract factory is not named abstract because it lacks implementation. IPizzaFactory is not an abstract factory. It's a factory method. You better familiarize yourself with these patterns before you start teaching them to others...

Comment: @slepic I see your confusion, but `IPizzaFactory` can not be a factory method simply because it's an interface. You can see relevant examples [here](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/abstract-factory/csharp/example) and [here](https://www.oodesign.com/abstract-factory-pattern).

Comment: @QuasiStellar it's you who is confused, being an interface is irrelevant. "factory method" is a creational design pattern. And so is "abstract factory". There is an interface and concrete implementation for both. The word "abstract" in the name of design pattern "abstract factory"  does not refer to the OOP concept of abstract classes in any way. It is "abstract" because it abstracts the consumer from details of the implementation, no matter how many implementations exist if any at all.

Comment: @QuasiStellar createPizza() is factory method. createItalianPizza() + createNewYorkPizza() on one interface is abstract factory. The difference simply is that abstract factory offers to create multiple different, and yet similar, objects, Factory method offers just one.

Comment: @QuasiStellar or as I like to put it: abstract factory is a pallete of factory methods

Comment: @slepic if you only need one method, you don't need to create a factory interface and separate classes for each factory. Since OP only implemented creation of one object, this whole logic can indeed be turned into a factory method, but they decided not to. The other answer sums it up very well.

Comment: @QuasiStellar That's right. I have already upvoted the other answer, but yours is totally misleading, sorry.